# Multiple rewrite cond in one htaccess file BUT

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get a URL shortener to work.
Instead of redirecting the link : http://urlshortner.com/33 to, say, yahoo.com, it just redirects it to http://urlshortner.com/yahoo.com.
But if I put the info from that .htaccess file that resides in my shortener subdir onto my MAIN .htaccess file (root level) the URL shortner redirect works correctly, but my MAIN page gives a 404 error.

Example:

I have many URLs on my server and my MAIN site on my server root.
So, my URL shortener is located at:
myserver/urlshortner which points to urlshortner dot com

and my main page is:
myserver/index.html which points to mymainpage dot com

I have an .htacess file at myserver/urlshortner/.htaccess that says:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

And my .htacess file at my root directory that forces all requests to https etc:

```
# Begin IP blocking #
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from xxx.xx.xxx
Allow from all
# End IP blocking #

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXXX\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.XXXXXX.com/$1 [R,L]

AddType application/xspf+xml .xspf .xspf
```

BUT, when I combine them like this:

```
    # Begin IP blocking #
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from xxx.xx.xxx
    Allow from all
    # End IP blocking #

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXXXXX\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.XXXXXX.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]

    AddType application/xspf+xml .xspf .xspf
```

The URL shortener works, but my main page gives a 404 error.

Any thoughts on this?